# Query a remote server's operating system?

Tags: perl, operating-system

is there a way to query a server for its OS type in Perl? For example, if I knew that a remote server was running Windows, I might send it a winver from my local machine and get the output to determine which version of Windows it's running. Yet, is there a way to be even more abstract and simply ask "what are you?"

Since CPAN is huge, I was wondering if there were a module that encapsulated this sort of functionality.

Comment: "server" is a wholly ambiguous term. So ambiguous that nobody can answer the question. Information that allows the question to be answered would be stating what protocols this "server" can respond to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get command-line access on the remove server, then you should be able to use [`%ENV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
jmaney> perl -e 'print "$ENV{OSTYPE}\n";'
linux
```

**Edit:**  It looks as though the key in Windows (or, at least on Windows 7 on my laptop) is `OS`.  So, unfortunately, the exact solution via `%ENV` is OS-dependent...  You could, however, check to see which of `$ENV{OS}` or `$ENV{OSTYPE}` is defined (and if they're both defined, then canonically pick which one you want to use), and proceed accordingly.

Comment: the op is looking to find the OS of a remote server. Your statement works on the 'local' machine (or assuming a login etc) ... and no, the dv is not mine..

Comment: And **if OP can get command-line access on the remote server** (as I indicated in the first sentence of my answer), then OP has a shot at figuring out the OS of the remote server.

Comment: If you can get command-line access on the remote server there's absolutely no sense in writing a Perl program to run on that server, because you can try things like `uname`.

Comment: Jack, this is a good answer, thanks. Sorry to confuse.. but I actually *can* get command-line access.. I know of uname and what not, but primarily wanted to see it accomplished via a Perl script from the local machine. The main question should have just focused on wondering if a CSPAN module could query a remote server, given an IP address, and get information about it. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no foolproof way to do this, but the HTTP `Server` header -- which the server isn't required to send -- often contains the OS. For example, it may look like this (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)):

```
    Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
```

[The Perl CGI module has an `http` function that gets the HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007007/how-do-i-access-the-http-header-of-request-in-a-cgi-script). You could use it like this:

```
my $server = $q->http('Server');
# Test $server for Windows, *nix, etc
# My Perl experience is minimal and I haven't used it in
# a while, so I'm not going to give an example here, but
# someone can feel free to edit one in.
```

CPAN probably has a module to do the testing on the `Server` header for you.

Comment: Which unfortunately I'm not able to assume. Regardless, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Wooble: You're right. Being a web developer, that's what I think of when I think of "server". Since he can get command-line access it doesn't really matter though.