# My CGI script not receiving custom headers

Tags: perl, http-headers, cgi, shopify, webhooks

I'm writing a CGI script (Perl on Apache, no other framework) that's supposed to be a webhook endpoint. The technical details are it's supposed to receive events from a Shopify store, but that's semi-irrelevant. Shopify tells me that in order to verify that the webhook came from them, I need to calculate the HMAC using a secret key they provide, and make sure it matches the value in the `X-SHOPIFY-HMAC-SHA256` header. I've used requestb.in to look at the webhook as it's sent, and I can verify that the http client they're using is sending the X-header.

However, when my CGI script runs, I only get the bog-standard headers. X-SHOPIFY-HMAC-SHA256 is neither found in Perl CGI module `http()` nor in the `%ENV` environment variables. (I read [How do I access the HTTP Header of request in a CGI script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007007/how-do-i-access-the-http-header-of-request-in-a-cgi-script) and [How to fetch HTTP headers in perl when using CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949276/how-to-fetch-http-headers-in-perl-when-using-cgi))

I'm using cgiwrap to get my script additional privileges, but that shouldn't stop me from seeing the headers right?

Comment: Which webserver or framework do you use?

Comment: Just plain Perl on Apache, no framework.

Comment: Can the people downvoting me please explain why they thought my question was ill-posed, and explain how it could be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain apache sets environment variables for HTTP headers. Try it without any wrapper first. You might also try `printenv.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n".Dumper(\%ENV);
```

Call printenv or your script manually to check if the caller might cause the problem:

```
curl -H "Foo: Bar" http://localhost/cgi-bin/printenv.cgi
```

You might also want to dump to a file if your script is being called as API.

See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Local requests seem to work.

Comment: Not sure what it was, but this helped me track it down. Perhaps an underscore/hyphen issue.

Comment: Also I'd use text/plain instead of text/html as the Content-type.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for the corrections. Wrote the answer on via Smartphone and obviously got some typos. :(